# Display app during phone call (Objective-C or Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phone-call

I can't find a way to display my app when the user calls someone through the default iPhone's Phone Application.
Is it possible to do that?
I'd like to show up a specific screen which looks like the iPhone's default one.

Comment: Why would you want to display a screen that looks like the default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** this is **NOT** possible because apps work in a sandboxed mode so they are unaware of any other apps running on the device.